# Why isn't the prop defined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vue-component

I have this code for my component:

```
<template>
    <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
    <img :src="imgLink"/>

</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';


let imgLink = ref()

export default {
    props: {
        'name': String,
        'imgurl': String
    }
}

fetch(imgurl).then(res => res.json()).then(json => imgLink.value = json.sprites.front_default)



</script>
```

But I get the error "'imgurl' is not defined" at the line with the fetch-function. I don't understand why it isn't defined since I define it as a String in the props.

Any help is appreciated.

I have only tried too make a separate variable and setting its value to the props value because I thought the problem might be using the prop as a link directly.

Comment: How do you expect `imgurl` to get a value? It's not defined as a variable or initialized to a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixin the `<script setup>` notation (using composition API) with the option API. You can either do :

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps } from 'vue';

let imgLink = ref()

const props = defineProps({
  name: String,
  imgurl: String
})

fetch(props.imgurl).then(res => res.json()).then(json => imgLink.value = json.sprites.front_default)
</script>
```

See : https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits

Or with the options API :

```js
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        'name': String,
        'imgurl': String
    },
    data: () => ({
       imgLink: null,
    }),
    created() {
        fetch(this.imgurl).then(res => res.json()).then(json => this.imgLink = json.sprites.front_default)
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The defineProps solution worked and i got the desired result but also an error saying "Destructuring the `props` will cause the value to lose reactivity". What does this mean?

Comment: @TageDanielsson indeed, you should avoid destructuring props. If the prop value (passed from parent component) changes, it won't have any effect on the child component. I edited my answer. 
See this [eslint rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-setup-props-destructure.html)